# No dual boot option for Windows on my machine

Tags: linux, windows

I just installed Kali Linux, dual booting with Windows 7. Problem is that there is no Windows 7 in the boot options and Kali Linux starts automatically.

I can not use Windows because there's no Windows 7 option.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, did you have a question?

Comment: @50-3 The question, obviously, is how to get a Windows booting option.

Comment: @slhck is it a question of how to boot to windows, how to restore the MBR for windows or what can be used to manage the boot process or once in Kali how can I reboot into windows. The question was poorly written and I honestly was unclear on what the question was.

Answer (score 4):

This depends, how you installed your Kali Linux on Windows 7, if you made changes to the Windows partition, windows 7 installation might be gone forever.
However, if you installed Kali to a seperate partition after setting up the swap correctly, the windows boot option might come back.

Try inserting a Windows 7 disc or boot from a Windows 7 pendrive, and launch startup repair.

Alternatively,
From your Ubuntu desktop, open up a terminal and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

To reinstall Grub, with all the options you had, you’ll need a linux live CD or pendrive. Once in a “live session”:

- Open a Terminal.
- Use sudo fdisk -l and locate Ubuntu’s partition.
- Mount said partition in /mnt (replace XY, with the correct letter &
  number)

  sudo mount /dev/sdaXY /mnt

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Make sure you have ***os-prober*** package installed.

> sudo apt-get install os-prober

This can be tested with:

> sudo os-prober

It will give an input like this if you haven't messed with Windows OS files:

> /dev/sda1:Microsoft Windows 7 Professional:Windows:chain

**Step 2**

> sudo update-grub2

Now the boot entry for windows  will appear in GRUB2.