# System does not boot to operating system

Tags: windows-7, laptop, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint on a system with Windows 7. After the installation completed, the system restarted to show me this message:

```
Intel UNDI PXE-2.0(build 083)
Copyright(c) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation
For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.1.1.2(09/06/12)

Check Cable Connection!
PXE-M0F Exiting Intel PXE ROM
```

This message is displayed repeatedly. Is it because I turned on updates with my installation?
Why would the installer download Intel drivers when I have AMD?

Meta-data that might solve the problem

The result of running fdisk for every drive is [here](http://pastebin.com/7WpYyLbq)

Some of the answers hinted at a possible loss of hard disk.Results of running lsscsi are                                   [here](http://pastebin.com/GxrU9Hn4)

I chose install alongside something else when installing Mint,I had to run bootinfoscript using my live CD.The results have been posted in a comment

And BTW guys I have grub and not grub2

Comment: Most importantly the result of running bootinfoscript https://db.tt/xN6kMBIn

Comment: This is the result of running sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/2476704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you haven't messed around with your boot  options lately.Go to BIOS and check if your hard disk is still present in the boot sequence.If it isn't , I think your Hard disk probably just died.It might be the reason why the machine jumping to PXE boot , which is next in boot sequence.

Try reconnecting the Hard disk.If you are lucky , it might just be a loose connection as well.

**Update**

*With reference to the chat message [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11538/discussion-between-ash-and-user2309862).*

1. Boot from the live CD.
2. Determine the partition number of your main partition. GParted can help you here. I'm going to assume in this answer that it's `/dev/sda2`, but *make sure you use the correct partition number for your system!*
3. Mount your partition:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  # make sure that sda2 is correct!
   ```
4. Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

   ```
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
   ```
5. `chroot` into your Ubuntu install:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
6. At this point, you're in your install, not the live CD, and running as root. Update grub:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

   If you get errors, go to step 7. (Otherwise, it is optional.)
7. Depending on your situation, you might have to reinstall grub:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   update-grub # I'm not sure if this is necessary, but it doesn't hurt.
   ```
8. If everything worked without errors, then you're all set:

   ```
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```
9. At this point, you should be able to boot normally.

If you cannot boot normally, and didn't do step 7 because there were no error messages, try again with step 7.

- Sometimes giving GRUB2 the correct *configuration* for your partitions is not enough, and you must actually install it (or reinstall it) to the Master Boot Record, which step 7 does. Experience helping users in chat has shown that step 7 is sometimes necessary even when no error messages are shown.*[(source)](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/182653)*
- [next step](https://superuser.com/a/676725/241659)

Comment: I could see three partitions in /dev from my live cd,Does this mean I still have a hard disk

Comment: Not necessarily , what does lsscsi return ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GxrU9Hn4

Comment: well , luckily ,you have .

Comment: now what do i do...

Comment: which dev partition do you have mint installed ?

Comment: i opted to install along with something else,so i dont know

Comment: in sdb or sda ?

Comment: i was not prompted for a choice when installing.how do i find out?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11538/discussion-between-ash-and-user2309862)

Comment: It did not work

Comment: worth my time :(

Comment: Ash,reinstalled grub,Linux Mint boots now...I cannot access windows from there or else where.What should I do?

Comment: @user2309862 did the chat messages helped in doing so ? use os prober to locate windows from mint.

Comment: Well,I used the last message I posted with some commands from ubuntuforum,I did it as su.sudo os-prober no volume groups found

Comment: Added a link to /boot/grub/menu.lst as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

PXE is **network boot.**
It is displayed because it's enabled.
The whole [PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) thing does nothing (for you. you don't need it), you can disable it.

The reason your computer does not boot, is that it cannot find **any** bootable drives.
That are configured in the BIOS to be tried, that is.

**So what about a solution?**
Well, I suspect Mint messed up the MBR.
You can:
- Install Mint again, and hope that GRUB will get installed this time...
- Use the Windows DVD and use startup repair. (You won't be able to boot Linux after this.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:
http://www.lancelhoff.com/restore-grub2-after-installing-windows/

Maybe your MBR got corrupted somehow and hard disk is no longer seen as bootable. Put in your liveCD, boot from it and try to reinstall grub according to the tutorial above.

Also, after you boot from LiveCD you can use

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

`/dev/sda` is your disk's name. It should list your partitions and their properties. Post the result here, that should be a bit helpful if my answer won't work.

More info about fdisk:
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/fdisk.htm

Comment: http://pastebin.com/daXaqEDa

Comment: This pastebin has results for every drive:http://pastebin.com/7WpYyLbq

Comment: `/dev/sda` is name of the device and `/dev/sdaX` is a partition name. The result for `/dev/sda` suggest, that you have no booting partition on your disk, so you can't boot from it. What's worse it seems that you have whole partitioning broken. Can you mount your hard disk after booting from LiveCD and see if there is any data left on it? Also: paste the second link into your question, maybe it will help someone else to give you better answer.

Comment: Result of running bootinfoscript https://db.tt/xN6kMBIn

Comment: Result of running lsscsi is http://pastebin.com/GxrU9Hn4

Comment: Linux seems to be installed on dev/sda2,I tried grub-install and grub2 update using chroot.It said
mint boot # sudo update-grub2 
sudo: unable to resolve host mint 
Generating grub.cfg ... 
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic 
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic 
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin 
No volume groups found 
done

Comment: After rebooting I tried using the sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt followed by chroot /mnt...did not work.it says failed to run /bin/bash...no such file or directory

Comment: Will reinstalling windows and repartitioning my hard drive help?Can I change any bios options to get it to work

Comment: should I even be installing Linux on my computer,it has uefi and mbr.

Comment: I couldn't mount my disk using gparted

Comment: I see no reason why you shouldn't install Linux, I have dual boot working just fine. Reinstalling system should do the trick, but you'll lose your data so let's not rush into it. But try to reinstall Linux - it seems, that it failed to install properly. And since it was a fresh installation the loss should be next to nothing.

Comment: i have installed and used mint alone before it caused a strange problem where everything but the border of anything disappears,then i dual booted with windows 8,never saw linux mint open,then dual booted with windows 7,could see nothing...does not even boot,i wonder what will happen if i reboot,the uefi thing is not going away.it has been a house of horrors all along,i also happen to have amd which means software rendering mode.

Comment: i have used linux before on an older machine,uefi seems so hostile....can you linkto a guide regarding a proper reinstall,i atleast should be ableto boot into windows....will removing linux allowmeto do that?

Comment: im really scared of what will happen if i do this again.if uninstalling linux mint saves my hard drive and allow me to access windows 7 should i do it,is there a repair option,can i use the live cd to uninstall linux mint

Comment: Added a pastebin of what happens when Itry and fix the grub: http://pastebin.com/WyME8gZ5

Comment: If you can mount Windows partition from LiveCD you can **and should** backup your data - that will make you a little bit less scared :) As for reinstalling Mint it should be pretty straightforward: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=103872

Comment: I did this:http://pastebin.com/L4AyHQEc,will it work

Comment: uninstalled grub2,installed grub and the abovepastebin,did i fix it?

Comment: After making a backup of your data maybe try to use `grub-install --recheck /dev/sda` from the tutorial I mentioned in my post. Also: did you issue `grub-upgrade` from LiveCD? Because if so, you most likely tried to overwrite grub on CD, which is not possible for obvious reasons.

Comment: The last pastebin looks optimistic. Only rebooting can verify if it went well.

Comment: i used chroot to /dev/sda2 which was mounted to /mnt/chroot,then i used bind for /dev ,/sys,/proc then i issued chroot and uninstalled grub2,installed grub and did grub-install /dev/sda followed by recheck..now should i do grub-upgrade?

Comment: Booted to mint without live CD,now what how can I get windows back too?

Comment: I don't see any other option than `grub-upgrade` right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11541/discussion-between-user2309862-and-darth-hunterix)

Comment: no rep...i ran grub-upgrade,command not found,grub -upgrade,invalid option

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Try `update-grub`

Comment: Tried it rebooted,did not work...grub menu only consists of Linux Mint

Comment: Are you able to access Windows partition from Linux? I mean mount it and look ad files?

Comment: Someone should either summarise these comments into the answer or just wait for the whole thread to be deleted

Comment: I summarised some of the diagnostic commands I ran into the question,could you summarise the rest into an answer.cannot access windows

Comment: sudo os-prober says No volume groups found,I have grub instead of grub2

Comment: Added a comment under the question that has a link to grub/menu.LST findings

Comment: @random So far we are only poking the laptop and trying to figure out what's wrong, there is little to summarize. Dear user2309862, It seems to me that you deleted your Windows partition during Mint installation. You should have no problem to access NTFS partition after booting Linux if it existed. The suspected that ever since you pasted the fdisk results, but I had hoped I was mistaken. Sadly, I don't know how to fix this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

have a check if your partition with the mbr installed is marked as active otherwise the bios doesn't know were the Filesystem(s) are installed and would not boot the disk.

Answer (score -1):

Your pc is set to boot from an external drive.

At start press F2 and enter the bios menu

In the "boot" section disable everything other then C: drive

Profit

Comment: Wil this show GRUB?

Comment: Removing the PXE Boot option,now displays a blank screen with a cursor repeatedly